# angular2 - How do 'imports' and 'exports' work in Angular2 modules?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am completely new to Angular2 and it has been very difficult to understand what is going on with the `@NgModule` **imports and exports in Angular2.**

Take the following code for example-:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(heroesRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
```

In the imports section **what am I importing ?** *The router module , or the forChild() function, or the module returned by the function forChild() ?*
Which one is it ?

Also when I export the `RouterModule` again, the [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#routing-module) says the following-:

> Our last step is to re-export the RouterModule. By re-exporting the
>   RouterModule, our feature module will be provided with the Router
>   Directives when using our Routing Module.

**So does that mean that whatever module imports the above NgModule, will have access to all the code in the RouterModule ?**

Is it sort of like if I write a custom header file in C that includes math.h, if I now use that header file I no longer need to include math.h in my programme separately. *Is my analogy correct ?*

Can someone explain the core concepts here, so that I don't get stumped every time I see new code.

Answer (score 35):

A Module in Angular2 is very similar to the Angular1 modules , which basically is a package containing all the bits and pieces that makes sense to be shipped together.

For example , if you have a LoginComponent which for some reasons is connected to a Service , which is LoginService, which does some http request to get some user information , you might create a LoginModule which ships LoginComponent and LoginService all together as LoginModule.

LoginService could also use some  interfaces , for example a UserInterface  , which again , would makes sense to be shipped to LoginModule to the consumer.

So if I'm your client and I'm going to use your general Login functionality , would makes it much easier for me to just import your LoginModule and all your goodies available to my AppComponent !

So , your LoginModule class ( which is nothing but a simple javascript file and a function )  should export LoginModule to be used by me :).

LoginModule would look like this:

```
   @NgModule({
      declaration:[LoginComponent , LogoutComponent], 
      exports: [
        LoginComponent , LogoutComponent
      ],
      providers:[LoginService]
    })
    export class LoginModule{

    }
```

So in my AppModule , I would import your LoginModule.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    LoginModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(heroesRoutes) // another imported module that I need beside the Login
  ]
})
```

BUT :

If I know your code and I don't want any of your extra functions and components and classes  and things and I just need to use your LoginComponent , I might prefer to only declare that I'm using LoginComponent and I don't want to import your massive LoginModule !

```
@NgModule({
  declaration:[LoginComponent],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(heroesRoutes)
  ]
})
```

This would only and only work if LoginComponent does not have any direct dependency on LoginService , other wise Angular would complain and say :

```
**No Provider for LoginService**
```

Which in that case , if you're a tough person and you're still not convinced to use LoginModule , you can help Angular and provide the LoginService like :

```
@NgModule({
  declaration:[LoginComponent],// declaring it 
  providers:[LoginService],// providing it
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(heroesRoutes)
  ]
});
```

So , this might continue and you might find it easier to just import the whole LoginModule and let the Module itself do all of the job .!

That's it with LoginModule.

---

Now , to answer your question regarding **forChild**.

The LoginModule might want to do some extra things when giving you it's classes which is not always needed , in that case you might have improved the LoginModule and added some sugar to it.

```
@NgModule({
   declaration:[LoginComponent , LogoutComponent], 
   exports: [LoginComponent , LogoutComponent],
   providers:[LoginService]
})  
export class LoginModule{
  public static logAndLoadModule(message){
     console.log('I first log and then give you my module');
     return {
      ngModule: LoginModule
     }
  }
  public static alertAndLoadModule(message){
      alert('I first alert and then give you my module');
     return {
      ngModule: LoginModule
     }
  }
}
```

Which , in this case , looks like the module can log something when it starts giving me it's package . So I might use it like this:

```
   @NgModule({
      imports: [
        LoginModule.logAndLoadModule(),
        RouterModule.forChild(heroesRoutes)
      ]
    })
```

Isn't **logAndLoadModule** this similar to **forChild** function of RouterModule ?

Yes it is , it still gives you LoginModule but it does some extra thing as well.

So you can still import LoginModule , but you can use it's alert and log as well.

UPDATE:

**export class LoginModule** , means , the current file ( probably login.module.ts or whatever )  is exporting a class called LoginModule which can be imported from other files and it has nothing to do with Angular , this is only typescript which will compile to javascript.

Where as

```
  @NgModule({
      exports: [
        LoginModulesBrother
      ]
    })
  export class LoginModule{

  }
```

Above is Angular2 specific language and means LoginModule is also Exporting LoginModulesBrother , so who ever is importing LoginModule , has also have access to to LoginModulesBrother.

So , LoginModulesBrother , is another module which is probably defined somewhere else like :

```
  @NgModule({
      // some other magic here 
  })
  export class LoginModulesBrother{

  }
```

So generally , import and export a **class** , which could be what ever ( a Module a component a pipe a simple function or anything ) is only typescript , but that exports array and imports array is only Angular specific language and means nothing to typescript .

Comment: Okay a few confusions. When you write `export class LoginModule`, why do you again include in the exports of the `NgModule` ? Second are the functions like `logAndLoadModule`, are they just defined by you or are they part of the spec ?

Comment: Okay but adding it in the exports of `@NgModule` is telling Angular2 that the class is exported, right ? Okay so in theory can I write a class without the `export` keyword and add it to the exports array in ngModule ? Would that be valid ? I mean I tell Angular2 that the class is exported but I don't tell typescript. Would that work ?

Answer (score 3):

If you use the `<router-outlet>` component or the `routerLink` or `routerLinkActive` directives, you need to add the `RouterModule` to `imports: []` of every module where you want to use any of these.

This is the same for any directive, component or pipe. Angular only instantiates them in a module if they are made known by an import.

If you add a module to `imports: []` all directives, components and pipes listed in exports become available to the importing module.

A module also can re-export other modules, which makes all exported directives, components and pipes of these modules available to the importing module.

See also

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html
- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ngmodule-faq.html

Answer (score 0):

From the [RouterModule](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterModule) docs:

- `forRoot` creates a module that contains all the directives, the given routes, and the router service itself.
- `forChild` creates a module that contains all the directives and the given routes, but **does not include the router service**.

You use `forRoot` to configure routing for your root module and `forChild` for you feature modules.

You don't need `router service` in feature modules because you only need one for your application, which you should configure in `AppRoutingModule` by convention(assuming your root module is named `AppModule`).

Using your code snippet as a example:

```
    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(heroesRoutes)
      ],
      exports: [
        RouterModule
      ]
    })
   export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

`RouterModule` has some declarations like `routerLink` or `routerLinkActive` that might be used by components in `AppModule`.

For those declarations to be available in `AppModule`, you either import `RouterModule` directly into `AppModule` or make it available via `AppRoutingModule` by exporting it.