# Angular 4 root module 'import' and 'imports'

Tags: angular, typescript

A typical root module in angular 4 looks like this

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

In the documentation, it is mentioned "In the example of the simple root module above, the application module needs material from within that browser module. To access that material, add it to the @NgModule metadata imports like this."
`imports: [ BrowserModule ],`

My questions are:

What does "the application module needs material from within that browser module" mean?

What is the difference between this import `import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';` and this one `imports: [ BrowserModule ],` ?

Could someone please help me understand the purpose of using `imports` in the root module?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular2 - How do 'imports' and 'exports' work in Angular2 modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41281780/angular2-how-do-imports-and-exports-work-in-angular2-modules)

Comment: AppModule =  application module .... BrowserModule is embedded in this.  import at top is used to locate where it is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What does "the application module needs material from within that
> browser module" mean?

It can mean several things. First, it may mean that `browser` module defines some providers that need to be provided be the global injector. It can also mean that components defined in the root module will use some declarable types from `browser` module. Actually, if you look at `BrowserModule` definition you will that it's both:

```
@NgModule({

  // global providers
  providers: [
    BROWSER_SANITIZATION_PROVIDERS,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useFactory: errorHandler, deps: []},
    {provide: EVENT_MANAGER_PLUGINS, useClass: DomEventsPlugin, multi: true},
    ...
  ],

  // declarable types - components/directives/pipes
  // declared in common and application modules
  exports: [CommonModule, ApplicationModule]
})
export class BrowserModule {
```

I suggest you read [Avoiding common confusions with modules in Angular](https://indepth.dev/posts/1056/avoiding-common-confusions-with-modules-in-angular)

> What is the difference between this import `import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';` and this one `imports: [ BrowserModule ]`

The difference is that the former imports `ESM` module and the latter imports Angular module. [ESM/Typescript modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) have nothing to do with Angular modules.