# Creating Angular module which can be shared?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I am pretty new angular 2,  I have a requirement to create a module say that `account module` which should be shared across two different projects say that project A and B.

I am not sure how to proceed with my design. Do I have to create an angular module in node JS? If anyone could help me on how to proceed to give some design idea I will take it further.

I tried googling it but no luck, to be frank, I don't know what to search for.

Note: I am using Angular 2

Comment: To use a module in different projects, you have to publish your module to `npm` and later need to install and import. Here are some [article1](https://medium.com/@OCombe/how-to-publish-a-library-for-angular-2-on-npm-5f48cdabf435), and [article2](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-create-library-in-angular-2-and-publish-to-npm-from-scratch-f2b1272d6266).. hope it help

Comment: Thanks Anoop this is what I was looking for. You made my day :)

Answer (score 0):

Create Module and export from NgModule

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [TestComponent],
  exports: [TestComponent],
  imports: [OtherModule],
  providers: []
})
export class TestModule{}
```

and Import same Module from different project

```
import {TestModule} from '<path of Test Module>'

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [NewComponent],
      exports: [NewComponent],
      imports: [TestModule], // import that module in NgModule 
      providers: []
    })
    export class NewModule{}
```

Hope this is helpful for you

I think learning imports and NgModule in Angular 2 are good start

Comment: components and directives should go under `declarations` not exports. `imports` and `exports` are precisely reserved for modules.

Comment: @bhanu, as you said components and directives go under declarations and even pipes and we can use components in exports in order use that "New Component" in another Module. Nice article for using components in declarations and exports to expose components as public and failing to include in both will make that component as private - http://blog.ng-book.com/introduction-to-ngmodules-components-dependency-injection-and-testing/

Comment: one more for reference - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41281780/angular2-how-do-imports-and-exports-work-in-angular2-modules

Answer (score 0):

Module Holds all the services,component and other module which are required by the component in your case it is account module
Once you are done with create account component next step will be configuration of module.

let take AccountManagementComponent.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-account-management',
  templateUrl: './account-management.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./account-management.component.css']
})
export class AccountManagementComponent implements OnInit {
 constructor(private  accountservice: AccountService, ) {}


ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Create New ts File Called Account Module in the same directory of AccountComponent.ts. Which includes all the services,component and other modules which are required to that component CommonModule is needed  directive as used in your component such as  NgIf, NgFor as follow:

```
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {CommonModule} from "@angular/common";
import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
import {AccountService} from "../shared/services/Account-data.service";
import {AccountManagementComponent} from "./account-management.component";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AccountManagementComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule],
  providers: [AccountService],
})
export class AccountModule {}
```

Finally instead of importing Component and services required by the component 
Need to import the module in the root module that is app.module.ts because that module contains all the things which are required to an component
In app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    AccountModule,
 ],
```